# grub problem after removing ubuntu from dual boot PC

Tags: dual-boot, grub, laptop, acer

I uninstalled the Ubuntu partition on my [Acer Predator](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/predator-home) system with Windows 8.1. I went into BIOS and set boot to my windows installation disk, but the PC now goes to the grub command line. I tried to go back to BIOS setup and it won't enter Setup.  I tried every command on your forum to access either win 8 or my installation disk with no success.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please provide each specific command you used and the result you got. Click [edit] and add them, line by line, to the end of your original question, so we can see what you actually tried and the results. Please do not use Add Comment, but instead use [edit] .Editing tips are at https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code .

Comment: The command string that worked follows.  However, it only worked once.  Insmod part_gpt + insmod chain + set root=(hd0,gpt2) + chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi + boot.  I got windows disk up and ran recovery keeping my files.  When it rebooted, it came and stalled at the logo.  Cant enter bios now grub doesn't  come up.  The commands I used were all related to selecting my boot location.  Sorry for the messy post, I'm on a phone

Comment: Jeff, did you miss the request, "_Please do not use Add Comment, but instead use [edit]_"? Please put your updates into your question, not here in the comments. Make it easy for people to read your question. Make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you do in installed software should ever prevent you from getting into the bios menu except flashing the bios. Hard power off your machine (usually press and hold the power button for up to 10 seconds).  Your bios will be accessable when you next power on.

What you've done is a common mistake, grub will not work if you remove /boot/grub which by default is on the same partition as Ubuntu.

However you are using EFI not legacy boot.  So grub has been installed along side the original windows boot loader. So windows boot loader will still be there.  You should be able to select this in your bios menu often under a heading "boot" or "boot sequence". It can sometimes be a different menu from the boot device menu and occasionally you may need to tell the bios where the efi file is (/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi ).

Some bios have a boot menu on startup if you press the right hotkey (often F10 or f12 but it varies). You may find windows is still listed in this menu.

Edit: If it is stuck on "entering setup" then theres a chance (a very small chance) that corruption in the EFI partition is crashing the bios as it tries to parse EFI. I've seen some take a few minutes I've never seen one crash and fail to get there. If you are able to get into the laptop then hard power off, remove the battery and pop the HD. Then put the battery back in and power on. If you can get into the bios with no hd, then it's a problem with the disk or contents. If not then it's a pure hardware problem.

If you can get into the bios like this then maybe put the hd back once to see if the problem magically goes away but if not... If this corruption is to blame then you will need to get the disk into a working PC to fix it.

Comment: I don't understand the bios problem either.  I hit delete, bios came up.  I changed boot order to my DVD, saved and exited.  Restarted and the grub menu came up.  I gave it the localhere the boot is.  (Hd0, gpt2)  windows and was in install mode.  I took the save files programs it did what it should have according to percent completed.  It locked up at logo, no grub menu nothing.  Decided to recheck bios and I get "entering setup" which it never does.  I've installed ubuntu on several of computers and have never seen anything like this

Comment: Oh and the hard power down didn't help.  Again thanks for the help.